# Two forms on same template in django. How to collaborate the template with the views.py?

Tags: python, django

I have a template with two forms like this and two textareas where the uploaded content will be returned:

```
   <form
            class="form-inline"
            role="form"
            action="/controlepunt140"
            method="POST"
            enctype="multipart/form-data"
            id="form_pdf"
            
          >
            <div class="form-group">
              {% csrf_token %} {{ form_pdf }}
              <button type="submit" name="form_pdf" class="btn btn-warning">Upload!</button>
            </div>
          </form>
          <div class="form-outline">
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea class="inline-txtarea form-control" cols="70" rows="25">
{{content}}</textarea
              >   <form
            class="form-inline"
            role="form"
            action="/controlepunt140"
            method="POST"
            enctype="multipart/form-data"
            id="form_excel"
          >
            <div class="form-group">
              {% csrf_token %} {{ form }}
              <button type="submit" name="form_excel" class="btn btn-warning">Upload!</button>
            </div>
          </form>

 <textarea class="inline-txtarea form-control" cols="65" rows="25">
{{content_excel}}</textarea
              >
```

and the views.py:

```
class ReadingFile(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = ProfileForm()
        return render(request, "main/controle_punt140.html", {
            "form": form
        })

    def post(self, request):       
        types_of_encoding = ["utf8", "cp1252"]
        submitted_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        content = ''

        if submitted_form.is_valid():
            uploadfile = UploadFile(image=request.FILES["upload_file"])

            name_of_file = str(request.FILES['upload_file'])
            uploadfile.save()

        for encoding_type in types_of_encoding:
            with open(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
                                   f"{uploadfile.image}"), 'r', encoding=encoding_type) as f:

                if uploadfile.image.path.endswith('.pdf'):
                    pass
                else:
                    content = f.read()

            return render(request, "main/controle_punt140.html", {
                'form': ProfileForm(),
                "content": content
            })

        return render(request, "main/controle_punt140.html", {
            "form": submitted_form,
        })
```

and forms.py:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.Form):
    upload_file = forms.FileField()
```

and urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [  
    path('', views.starting_page, name='starting_page'),
    path('controlepunt140', views.ReadingFile.as_view(), name='controlepunt140')
]
```

So this works for the first upload function(pdf). The output is returned to the textarea.

But how to have it also work with the second upload function content_excel?

I.E: how to distinguish the two upload functions?

So this part:

```
return render(request, "main/controle_punt140.html", {
                                    'form': ProfileForm(),
                                    "content": content
                        })

                            return render(request, "main/controle_punt140.html", {
                                "form": submitted_form,
                    })
```

Would be double? one for pdf and one for excel

Comment: You forgot the ending ">" in your textarea (Just an observation).

Comment: @JDODER. Not. I didnt forgot. It is the '>' next to <form. You see it?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not used to the formatter you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the name of the submit buttons:

```
#FORM PDF
<button type="submit" name="form_pdf" class="btn btn-warning">Upload!</button>

#FORM EXCEL
<button type="submit" name="form_excel" class="btn btn-warning">Upload!</button>
```

So, in your views.py you can distinguish them on this way:

```
if request.POST.get('form_pdf'):
   ....
elif request.POST.get('form_excel'):
   ....
```

Comment: #LaCharcaSoftware. Thank you. But how to get the correct indentation level?